# need image to show on button alongside text

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to make buttons that will link to the pages of the products shown by their picture and title. the picture however wont show up.

```
const clothes = [
  [
    "1",
    "Blue Floral Broderie Ruched Tie Front Crop Top",
    "https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/tops/blue-floral-broderie-ruched-tie-front-crop-top/p/800379749",
    "https://media3.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/800379749/womens/clothing/tops/pale-blue-floral-broderie-ruched-tie-front-crop-top.jpg?strip=true&qlt=80&w=1024"
  ],
  [
    "2",
    "DRAPED LINEN DRESS",
    "https://www.zara.com/uk/en/draped-linen-dress-p04437278.html?v1=120193630&v2=1882775",
    "https://static.zara.net/photos///2021/I/0/1/p/4437/278/800/2/w/850/4437278800_1_1_1.jpg?ts=1626285850736"
  ]
];

for (let i = 0; i < clothes.length; i++) {
  var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var img = '<img scr=clothes[i][3] id = "myBtn"/>';
  x.id = i + 1;
  x.innerHTML = img + clothes[i][1];
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  document.getElementById(i + 1).addEventListener("click", function () {
    link(clothes, this.id);
  });
}
```

CSS

```
#myBtn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: "scr=clothes[i][3]" is just written as a string in the code you showed, not as variables

Comment: To use variables inside strings you need to concatenate them like: `'<img scr="' + clothes[i][3] + '" id="myBtn"/>'` or use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)